# how to avoid silence while playing audio file in xmarin forms media player

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to play an audio file with extention .wav. when I press play I dont hear the sound. How to stop the audio

Code:

```
 using Plugin.AudioRecorder; // you have to download from nuGetPackage
 using Xamarin.Essentials;

 private AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
  

  public NewEvent()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Media>();
    audioPlayer.Play("alert.wav");
  }

  private void StopPlay_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     audioPlayer.Stop();
  }
```

Comment: What permission should be checked?

Comment: I dont want to record I want to hear audio

Comment: I followed tutorial on youtube To play an audio and used it

Comment: Visual Studio Xamarin forms. I run projenct on Tablet android 13

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I put audio file to "Assets" folder. And changed Build Action of my audio file in properties to AndroidAsset. Now it works